# Which CSV-file to edit for correct translation for item TAX

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

I'm changing Magento invoice (translation & coloring) and everything went well
i.e. Mage_tax.csv contains 'Grand Total (Incl. Tax)' and I can translate it into Ducth. But I can locate the correct file which contains the word TAX. I found severall and I've translated it but it didn't show up in the invoice. Can somebody please point me to the rifght file to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All translations relating to Invoices can be found in the file Mage_Sales.csv.

If you are looking for all references for the phrase tax, it can be found in the following files.

```
./en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
./en_US/Mage_Api2.csv
./en_US/Mage_Bundle.csv
./en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
./en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv
./en_US/Mage_Cms.csv
./en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
./en_US/Mage_Downloadable.csv
./en_US/Mage_GoogleCheckout.csv
./en_US/Mage_Payment.csv
./en_US/Mage_Paypal.csv
./en_US/Mage_Reports.csv
./en_US/Mage_Rss.csv
./en_US/Mage_Sales.csv
./en_US/Mage_Tax.csv
./en_US/Mage_Weee.csv
./en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
```